# Creating sections each with title pages in beamers slides

Tags: beamer, titles

I'm writing up my dissertation defense slides. I would like to have a title page for each of three chapters. Specifically, I want to be able to replicate the box that the dissertation title is in for each of the chapters as I get to that section. Things I don't want: my name, university, and the date. So how do I get the title of each chapter in the same style box that the main title is in? Thanks in advance.

```
\title{This style box is what I want to replicate three other times in the slides.}
\author[Not needed]
\institute{I don't want this.}
\date{I don't want this either}
```

Comment: Which `beamer` theme(s) are you using?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina How can we define this command(\AtBeginSection) when using emacs org export to beamer ? Thanks.

Comment: How to introduce 'noframenumbering' option so that the slide with the section title does not increase the slide counter?
Thank you!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This can be easily done using `\AtBeginSection` to place a `frame` with the section title (`\insertsectionhead`) inside a `beamercolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably, depending on the theme used (which was not mentioned in the question), you will need to adjust the settings for the box; in particular, you might need to deactivate the option `shadow` and/or `rounded` by setting them to `false`.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. Now to complicate things. I am using the Frankfurt theme, so the section names are at the top of all the slides. How could I use this code to put the full titles in boxes but keep the names of sections short on the top bar?

Comment: @interesteduser Please, in this site we try to keep just one question per post. If you have additional questions, feel free to open a new question.

Comment: Your right. If you would please check out the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178809/beamer-section-titles-with-a-shorten-title-in-top-bar-of-slides

Comment: @interesteduser answer provide there too :) Don't forget that you can accept answers that you consider solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: This solves my problems too, but somehow the tableofcontents slide doesn't show up. Could you spell some magic so I could have the toc frame back?

Comment: I have a problem. The name of A section randomly appears at the top of the whole presentation

Comment: If I wanted the same for subsections? I tried using ``\AtBeginSubSection`` and ``\insertsubsectionhead`` at the appropriate places, but it didn't work. There's more to it? Thanks.

Comment: @PatrickT, okay so my hungarian is a bit rusty. ``AtBeginSubsection`` will work! (no capital letter for the second s)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the same thing, and the following outline can be also useful.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usetheme{Warsaw}
% or ...

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title[Short Paper Title]{Title As It Is In the Proceedings}
\subtitle{Include Only If Paper Has a Subtitle}
\author[Author, Another]{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}
\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere]{\inst{1}Department of Computer Science\\
University of Somewhere\and \inst{2}Department of Theoretical Philosophy\\
University of Elsewhere}
\date[CFP 2003]{Conference on Fabulous Presentations, 2003}

\makebeamertitle

%\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{institution-logo}{institution-logo-filename}
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{institution-logo}}

\AtBeginSubsection[]{%
  \frame<beamer>{ 
    \frametitle{Outline}   
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection] 
  }
}

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
\begin{frame}{Outline}

\tableofcontents{}

\end{frame}

\section{Motivation}

\subsection[Basic Problem]{The Basic Problem That We Studied}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. Use Uppercase Letters.}

\framesubtitle{Frame subtitles are optional. Use upper- or lowercase letters.}
\begin{itemize}
\item Use Itemize a lot.

\pause{}
\item Use very short sentences or short phrases.

\pause{}
\item These overlays are created using the Pause style.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> You can also use overlay specifications to create overlays.
\item<3-> This allows you to present things in any order.
\item<2-> This is shown second.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative.}
\begin{block}<1->{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Untitled block.
\item Shown on all slides.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}<2->{Some Example Block Title}
\begin{itemize}
\item $e^{i\pi}=-1$.
\item $e^{i\pi/2}=i$.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Previous Work}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }
\begin{example}<1->
On first slide. 
\end{example}

\begin{example}<2->
On second slide.
\end{example}

\end{frame}

\section{Our Results/Contribution}

\subsection{Main Results}
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }
\begin{theorem}
On first slide.
\end{theorem}


\pause{}
\begin{corollary}
On second slide.
\end{corollary}

\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}{Make Titles Informative. }
\begin{columns}[t]

\column{5cm}
\begin{theorem}<1->
In left column.
\end{theorem}


\column{5cm}
\begin{corollary}<2->
In right column.\\
New line
\end{corollary}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\subsection{Basic Ideas for Proofs/Implementations}

\section*{Summary}
\begin{frame}{Summary}
\begin{itemize}
\item The \alert{first main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
\item The \alert{second main message} of your talk in one or two lines.
\item Perhaps a \alert{third message}, but not more than that.
\end{itemize}
\medskip{}

\begin{itemize}
\item Outlook
\begin{itemize}
\item What we have not done yet.
\item Even more stuff.
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\appendix

\section*{Appendix}

\subsection*{For Further Reading}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{For Further Reading}

\beamertemplatebookbibitems
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Author1990}A. Author. \newblock\emph{Handbook of Everything}.\newblock
Some Press, 1990.\beamertemplatearticlebibitems

\bibitem{Someone2002}S. Someone.\newblock On this and that\emph{.}
\newblock\emph{Journal on This and That}. 2(1):50\textendash 100,
2000.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```