# How to have major titles on frames with individual frametitles in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have a division like

- Diseases

  - ... [many frames]
- How to develop Diagnostics

  - Common Diagnostics
  - ... [many frames]
- How to Diagnose and Treat

  - ... [many frames]

Dummy code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\begin{document} 
\title{Diagnostics}
\author{Masi}

\begin{titlepage}
1.11.2015.
\end{titlepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\part{Diseases}
\frametitle{How can you define a disease?}
\end{frame}
... [many frames]

\begin{frame}
\part{How to develop Diagnostics}
\frametitle{common approaches}
\end{frame}
--- [many frames]

\begin{frame}
\part{How to diagnose and treat?}
\frametitle{Diagsose Disease A, ...}
...
\end{frame}
--- [many frames]

\end{document}
```

where many pages. I know that you can have somehow major frametitles or something similar but could not find how to do it. 
It is possible that the *part* command is not the right way.

How can you have major titles for many frames such that the frame can have individual frametitles?

Comment: Shouldn't the `\part`s be outside the frames?

Comment: I would use sections instead of parts, by the way.

Comment: How can you have a subsection in frametitle?

Comment: I knew there would be a question that is completely ubnclear to me. Please edit the questions by adding this detail. Please explain in one or two sentences.

Comment: @Johannes_B Why would you use sections instead of parts? If the contents is too long, part would be the natural choice, allowing each part to have sections. In any case, that dependes to the OP and the little information provided is not enough to decide which is better :)

Comment: @Johannes_B Using \part you can have individual ToCs, for example and some other features which are not available with section. Again,. info in the question is not enough to make a decision about this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Agreeing with the last two points. This could be just as well a lecture of several topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can beachieved using

```
\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}
```

which will create, for each `\part` a frame having a centered heading of the form

```
Part #

Part Title
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\title{Diagnostics}
\author{Masi}

\AtBeginPart{\frame{\partpage}}

\begin{document}

\part{Diseases}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{How can you define a disease?}
\end{frame}

\part{How to develop Diagnostics}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{common approaches}
\end{frame}

\part{How to diagnose and treat?}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Diagsose Disease A, ...}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, `\part` should be used outside `frame`; a part has many frames (having a frame with `\part`s in it is not correct and will produce undesired results.)

If you decide that you don't want `\part`, but `\section` instead, there's a similar approach using  `\AtBeginSection`. Have a look at [`this answer of mine`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178803/3954) to [Creating sections each with title pages in beamers slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178800/3954) for an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! Your comment thread clears the thing to me too. It has been a natural choice for me to use parts because of extensive content and individual TOCs.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativ, use `\section`s and have them displayed in th header for orientation of your viewers. If yhere really are that many frames, they might lose track or fall asleep ;-)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\title{Diagnostics}
\author{Masi}
\begin{document} 

\frame{\maketitle}

\section{Diseases}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{How can you define a disease?}
\end{frame}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{frame}{Diseases sub\x}
        \x
    \end{frame}
}

\section{How to develop Diagnostics}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{common approaches}
\end{frame}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{frame}{Diseases sub\x}
        \x
    \end{frame}
}

\section{How to diagnose and treat?}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Diagsose Disease A, ...}
    ...
\end{frame}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {%
    \begin{frame}{Diseases sub\x}
        \x
    \end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```