# How to deactivate AtBeginSection for particular sections?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I have been using AtBeginSection to insert a title page at the beginning of a new section (following the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/creating-sections-each-with-title-pages-in-beamers-slides)). The title page follows the format of the beamer theme. However, I want to deactivate this automatic title page or change the formatting for some specific sections. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the optional argument of `\AtBeginSection` and `\section*` to insert a different code at the beginning of some sections. So you can use an empty optional argument for `\AtBeginSection` and `\section*` for the specific section without automatic title page.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\section*{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section three
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

**Update**

If you can not use the starred version of `\section` because you need the bookmark, then maybe you can use `\newif` and define commands to switch for the next section or all following sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newif\ifSectionTitlePage
\newcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagefalse}

\newcommand\AllSectionsWithTitlePage{%
  \SectionTitlePagetrue
  \renewcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagetrue}%
}
\newcommand\AllSectionsWithoutTitlePage{%
  \SectionTitlePagefalse
  \renewcommand*\SectionTitlePagedefault{\SectionTitlePagefalse}%
}
\newcommand\NextSectionWithTitlePage{\SectionTitlePagetrue}
\newcommand\NextSectionWithoutTitlePage{\SectionTitlePagefalse}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \ifSectionTitlePage
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
  \fi
  \SectionTitlePagedefault
}

\AllSectionsWithTitlePage% <- enable the title pages

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\NextSectionWithoutTitlePage% <- disable the title page for the next section
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section three
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above but with a bookmark for section 2 too.

Comment: Thank you. With the starred section, however, the section name disappears from the bookmarks. Is there a way to use the optional argument of AtBeginSection and maintain the section name in the bookmarks?

Comment: @user115089 See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want to use a starred section for some reason (personally I would use the [solution of esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383393/36296)), you could redefine `\AtBeginSection[]{}` within a group:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

{
\AtBeginSection[]{}
\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}
}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section three
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```