# Shifting the title page to the middle of the presentation in Beamer

Tags: beamer, titles

Is it possible to put the title slide to somewhere in the middle of the presentation when I create my presentation with Beamer? That is, suppose I want to show a couple of slides in the very beginning of my presentation, and after these slides I want to show the title slide (i.e., the slide that includes the title, authors and etc.). I've seen a [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/creating-sections-each-with-title-pages-in-beamers-slides) where some nice people discussed on creating sections in the presentation, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `beamer` comes with `\againframe`, which allows you to repeat a given frame. So you may just use that to repeat the title page.

Comment: Thanks @marmot for the quick answer, and also for welcoming me. I'll check `\againframe`, that looks promising. One thing I need to check, I don't want to repeat the title page. I want to use only one frame for title page, but I want to put this frame to somewhere around 3rd slide. Thanks again.

Comment: Isn't the title page generated by something like `\begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}`? If so, can't you just move that frame? If this does not work, you may want to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a little document that shows what you are doing.

Comment: I didn't cover the title page with `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`. But, anyhow, I just solved the problem, and posted an answer below. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it is pretty straightforward to solve this problem. What I needed to solve this problem was just moving `\maketitle` command into the middle where I want to show the title page. I put all the information that I want to use in the title (such as the authors) with the proper commands before `\begin{document}`, and then I moved `\maketitle` into the middle which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I decided by creating a separate .tex file for the first page and including it in the middle of the presentation with the `\include` command. Follow mwe:

Main file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, serif]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}


\title[]{Test I}
\subtitle[]{}
\author[Alexandre Loures]{Alexandre Loures}
\institute{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{}{\ 

test I

}

\end{frame}

\include{title} % <= here comes the file created the part

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{}{\

test II

}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The other file created the part (which I called title.tex) is as follows:

```
\section{}

\title[]{Test II}
\subtitle[]{}
%\author[]{}
\institute{}
\date{}

\maketitle
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]