# Changing a section page style

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I'm having a trouble with changing a section page style. What I have now is this:

[image]

What I want is to remove the "section 1" above the blue box, and to remove the box as well, and to add the section number in Roman to the section title (Introduction, here) so that the outcome should be 'I. Introduction' with centered, 12 pt.

I was able to remove only the section number, but not the blue box by following the code suggested in [Creating sections each with title pages in beamers slides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178800/creating-sections-each-with-title-pages-in-beamers-slides)

The code therein was:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @marmot Thanks for comment, I edited.

Answer (score 3):

Building on [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178803/121799).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
    \usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section one
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
test frame for section two
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for anwer. Can I know how to write the section number in Roman and to change font size?

Comment: @JJW Replace `\usebeamerfont{title}\thesection. \insertsectionhead\par%` by `\Large\Roman{section}. \insertsectionhead\par%`, or replace `\Large` by whatever font size you want.